# FIlter out specific keys with values from JSON in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a dynamically generating table in javascript and I have a JSON that I need to filter specific information out of

### JSON to pull from (courseList)

```json
let courseList = [
        {
            "Line": 81,
            "Department": "BUS",
            "Number": 344,
            "Section": 1,
            "Title": "MANAGEMENT OF INFORMATION SYSTEMS",
            "Faculty": "Smith, John",
            "Openings": 2,
            "Capacity": 30,
            "Status": "Open",
            "Day": "MWF",
            "StartTime": "1:25:00 PM",
            "EndTime": "2:20 PM",
            "Campus": " Main Campus",
            "Building": " Science and Engineering",
            "Room": " SE 341 Computer Science Lab",
            "Credits": 3,
            "Start Date": "8\/30\/2021",
            "End Date": "12\/17\/2021\r\n"
        },
        {
            "Line": 167,
            "Department": "CSC",
            "Number": 133,
            "Section": 2,
            "Title": "SURVEY OF COMPUTER SCIENCE",
            "Faculty": "Scott, John",
            "Openings": 6,
            "Capacity": 15,
            "Status": "Open",
            "Day": "H",
            "StartTime": "2:00:00 PM",
            "EndTime": "4:50 PM",
            "Campus": " Main Campus",
            "Building": " Science and Engineering",
            "Room": " SE 341 Computer Science Lab",
            "Credits": 0,
            "Start Date": "8\/30\/2021",
            "End Date": "12\/17\/2021\r\n"
        }
    ]
```

And I would like to run some kind of method to generate another JSON from the existing one. To look something like this

### Expected result

```json
let filteredCourses = [
        {
            "Title": "MANAGEMENT OF INFORMATION SYSTEMS",
            "Faculty": "Smith, John",
            "Openings": 2,
        },
        {
            "Title": "SURVEY OF COMPUTER SCIENCE",
            "Faculty": "Scott, John",
            "Openings": 6,
        }
    ]
```

I'm still new to javascript but I know there is a filter method on arrays that I have used, but that only gave me the keys or the values from my coursesList. I have also tried using the push method without much luck.

Is there some way to either filter out the specific key and value pairs that I need directly into a JSON, or can I filter out both the keys and values separately and combine them? I'm not sure what the best method would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter function is used to filter elements out of an array based on a function you define.

For example, if you want to filter out all courses where there are no openings, you'd use

```
const filteredCourse = courseList.filter(a => a.Openings > 0);
```

But what you want to do is perform an operation on each element. For that you want to use map. Like this:

```
const filteredList = courseList.map(a => ({ Title: a.Title, Faculty: a.Faculty, Openings: a.Openings }));
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const courseList = [
    {
        "Line": 81,
        "Department": "BUS",
        "Number": 344,
        "Section": 1,
        "Title": "MANAGEMENT OF INFORMATION SYSTEMS",
        "Faculty": "Smith, John",
        "Openings": 2,
        "Capacity": 30,
        "Status": "Open",
        "Day": "MWF",
        "StartTime": "1:25:00 PM",
        "EndTime": "2:20 PM",
        "Campus": " Main Campus",
        "Building": " Science and Engineering",
        "Room": " SE 341 Computer Science Lab",
        "Credits": 3,
        "Start Date": "8\/30\/2021",
        "End Date": "12\/17\/2021\r\n"
    },
    {
        "Line": 167,
        "Department": "CSC",
        "Number": 133,
        "Section": 2,
        "Title": "SURVEY OF COMPUTER SCIENCE",
        "Faculty": "Scott, John",
        "Openings": 6,
        "Capacity": 15,
        "Status": "Open",
        "Day": "H",
        "StartTime": "2:00:00 PM",
        "EndTime": "4:50 PM",
        "Campus": " Main Campus",
        "Building": " Science and Engineering",
        "Room": " SE 341 Computer Science Lab",
        "Credits": 0,
        "Start Date": "8\/30\/2021",
        "End Date": "12\/17\/2021\r\n"
    }
]
    
const filteredList = courseList.map(a => ({ Title: a.Title, Faculty: a.Faculty, Openings: a.Openings }));
 
console.log(filteredList);
```

Read up on map() filter() and reduce(). They're really useful functions, if somewhat hard to wrap one's head around sometimes.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, that was so much easier than all the other ways I was trying to do it. I haven't heard of map before, I'll definitely have to read on exactly how it works to make use of it later. Thanks again!